# Change permissions for files created by docker daemon service

Tags: ubuntu, docker, umask

I'm trying to change the default permissions assigned to files when created by the docker daemon by changing the default `umask`. The docker daemon service runs as root and creates the files with `umask` of root. I tried changing the `umask` by adding a command to `/etc/init.d/docker` and also passed the desired `umask(000)` as an option to start-stop-daemon but none of them seem to be working. How can I change the default permissions assigned to files created by docker daemon?

Edit: I am trying to set the default permissions for files and folders created by the docker daemon on the host and not within a container. For instance, if a folder on host machine, mapped within a container, doesn't exist, docker automatically creates the folders and assigns permissions based on default umask(which is that of root).

Comment: Which files.created.by docker are you referring? Normally as a user launching containers, you don't deal directly with the files. Do you mean the images and files created within the overlay file system?

Comment: @Otheus If I map a folder on host machine to a folder within the container and if that folder doesn't exist on host machine, Docker automatically creates the folder on host machine.

Comment: So *when* you instantiate a container, sicker is creating folders on the host, and doing so without the permissions you need. Please update the question to clearly reflect this. I think I know what the problem is.

Comment: @Otheus I thought it would be clear that I'm trying to influence permissions of the folders on host machine since I'm trying to change umask of the docker daemon which runs on host machine and not within a container.

Comment: Because there are different use cases. Docker creates different files for different reasons. Which files impacts the answer. That is why I would like you to modify the question, because even after your edit, I cannot answer the question in general. But if your question regards ONLY the case in the previous comment, that has an answer

Comment: Ah I see. Sorry I forgot to mention this in my previous comment - I did edit the question already to mention this specific scenario. If the question still isn't clear, please do let me know what more changed are required and I can edit it again.

Comment: Also, could you also enlighten me about other files created by docker as well? I'm fairly new to docker and would like to know. Pointing me to reading material is also fine with me :).

Comment: Looks like you just need to run container with '-u UID' option or use 'USER' directive in Dockerfile.

Comment: @crazyh As far as I know, the USER directive controls the user with whose privileges the process runs inside the container. I don't see how that will help fix the permissions of folder created on the host machine where the container is running.

Comment: It is not clear that you need root privileges in container. As I understand you just want to say Docker 'create files in shared volume with specified UID/GID'

I use the following hack for my containers:

`FROM centos:6
    ARG GID=500
    ARG UID=500
    RUN groupadd -g ${GID} user && useradd -g user -u ${UID} user
    USER user`

The I built image with `--build-arg GID=$(id -g) --build-arg UID=$(id -u)`.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the issue. Suppose /home/test/shared on host is to be mounted at /var/shared_test in the container but /home/test/shared doesn't exist on host. Docker daemon automatically creates the folder /home/test/shared before mounting but it's not possible to write to /var/shared_test because of the permissions on host machine. I found that I can fix this by giving write permission to everyone and that's why I'm trying to change the umask for docker daemon.

Answer (score 0):

Docker containers typically and by design run in unprivileged mode. When a process in its container runs as root, the process uid of 0 is mapped to the host OS as a different user (typically "nobody"). This, In order for any process within the container to read files from the host OS, those files must be world readable. Presumably, (caveat emptor since I'm not familiar with the code) Docker disregards the umask settings to ensure the directory it created via the -v option is actually readable by the container.

I'm not so sure about files created within the container via btrfs or overlayfs, whether these files, which are accessible by the host OS, must be publically readable. I'm also not sure if The creation of those files is handled within the container or on the Host OS.

Comment: Actually, the Docker daemon doesn't disregard the umask settings of the user it runs as(root) on host machine. The non-existent, shared folders created on the host machine have permissions assigned using the default umask for root. I'd like to override that and specify the folder to be world writeable so that the process inside the container can create files in the folder.

Comment: If it honored umask, it would do that.

Comment: Ah my bad - somehow I misunderstood you. I guess you were trying to say that Docker probably has an internal override of any umask settings passed to it.

Comment: It's an educated evidence-based guess

Comment: Keep in mind, docker is under rapid development and has a solid issue/feature request system in place at github.